# Count Day Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have date range (e.g "20170301" and "20170701") and the table:

```
id name  start    end
1  first 2017-01-01 2017-10-01 (yyyymmdd)
2 second 2017-02-01 2017-02-01``
3 third  2017-02-01 2017-06-01
```

I have to count whether there is some event in every day from range or not
and return these dates.

e.g 20170301 - there is two events -> count=2 -> select this
    20170401 - 2 ...
    ...
    20170701 - there is no events -> count=0 -> do not select this

my query includes only start_date:

```
select to_char(t.start_date, 'yyyymmdd') as DAY
from table t
where to_char(t.start_date, 'yyyymmdd') between 20170301 and 20170304
group by to_char(t.start_date, 'yyyymmdd')
having count(*) > 0
```

I should group by every day of my input range to figure out if there is at least one event on every day of range.
(some kind of group by increment every day of range).

Is it possible two implement or could you recommend different approach?

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING? When you look at the main page, how many questions do you see where people are SHOUTING IN ALL CAPS? The answer: None besides yours. The reason: It's rude, it makes your question harder to read, and it won't get you an answer any quicker. There are two Shift keys on your keyboard, one on each side, to make them easier to use, because doing so improves readability. Please get out of the habit of SHOUTING your questions now. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't post an answer. I mentioned an issue with your conduct here, and edited your post to remove the inappropriate content. Your comment in reply has no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, name, start_date, end_date ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'first',  DATE '2017-01-01', DATE '2017-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'second', DATE '2017-02-01', DATE '2017-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'third',  DATE '2017-02-01', DATE '2017-06-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH calendar ( day ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + 1 FROM calendar WHERE day < DATE '2017-07-01'
)
SELECT day, COUNT(id)
FROM   calendar
       INNER JOIN
       table_name
       ON ( day BETWEEN start_date AND end_date )
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```